# changing sharepoint weekly Timer Job to daily via central administration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am new to sharepoint and I want some help.
I programmatically created a timer job for weekly schedule.
Now I want to change it to daily schedule directly via central administration and not via coding. Can I do it? if yes then how

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Central Administration website has a Timer Job Status page on which you can check the status of a timer job and a Job Definitions page on which you can edit the timer job definition. You can find links to these pages in Central Administration, on the Monitoring page, in the Timer Jobs section. You can click Review job definitions to see a list of all timer jobs, or click Check job status to see scheduled and running timer jobs.

**You can specify timer job schedules on the Edit Timer Job page**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Browse the Central admin..

```
Go to Central admin > Monitoring > Review Job Definitions > Select/Click the Your Timer job
```

Now you will change it from weekly to Daily.

Or you can try powershell to do this.

```
Get-SPTimerJob "name of your custom timer job" | Set-SPTimerJob -Schedule "daily at sat 5:00"
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607916(v=office.15).aspx